# Passing multiple values as method parameter

Tags: java, methods

I have a simple program to replicate people eating in a restaurant and the items they order.

The following is my Diner class, to create an object representing a person:

```
package dinersbill;

public class Diner {

    private String name;

    public Diner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Next is my Item class, representing food items people might order:

```
package dinersbill;

public class Item {

    String name;
    double price;
    Diner buyer;

    public Item(String name, double price, Diner buyer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.buyer = buyer;
    }

}
```

I want to have the program so that items may be assigned to more than one Diner if the user wishes. How would this be done?

Comment: you could use a Map<Item, List<Diner>>

Comment: Can you change the title, or is the problem just to have a method take a `List<Item>` parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the reationship between `Diner` and `Item` the other way around : a `Diner` *is composed of* `Item`s.

For instance, you can put an `ArrayList<Item>` into your `Diner` class and have a method to initialise the diner with several dishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List of Diners inside an Item

```
public class Item {

    String name;
    double price;
    List<Diner> buyers;

    public Item(String name, double price, List<Diner> buyers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.buyers = buyers;
    }

    //You can still have another constructor for a single Diner like this
    public Item(String name, double price, Diner diner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        ArrayList<Diner> diners = new ArrayList<Diner>();
        diners.add(diner);
        this.buyers = diners;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution is to rethink your model. Is there really a one-to-many relationship between Item and Diner?

A more natural relationship would probably be to reverse it and let Diner hold several Items in a List-object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a java collection, instead of a single String in your Diner class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

However, I'm certain this isn't the effect you're going for (you want to have more than one Diner order the same thing, right?)

If so, you just need to instantiate a new item for each Diner. Instead of having the Item assigned to the Diner, why not have the Diner assigned to the Item? That way you can instantiate the same item to multiple Diners.

Basically, you want a reference to an Item in your Diner class, but not a reference of Diner in your Item class. Then you can say

new Diner("Bob", new Item("Cheesecake", 2.50));

and that will create a new Diner named "Bob" who has ordered a cheesecake.

```
public class Diner {

    private String name;
    private Item item;

public Diner(String name, Item item) {
    this.name = name;
    this.item = item;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```